# fstream isnt reading from a text file after two lines

Tags: c++, console, fstream

im struggling with this part of code , no matter what i try i cant get it to read into a record after two lines

the text file contains

```
Mickey Mouse 
12121
Goofy
24680
Andy Capp
01928
Quasi Modo
00041
end
```

and the code is

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct record          
{               
char name[20];
int number;
 };



void main()
{


record credentials[30];
    int row=0; 
fstream textfile;//fstream variable
textfile.open("credentials.txt",ios::in);
textfile.getline (credentials[row].name,30);
//begin reading from test file, untill it reads end
while(0!=strcmp(credentials[row].name,"end"))
{ 

    textfile>>credentials[row].number;

    row++;
    //read next name ....if its "end" loop will stop
    textfile.getline (credentials[row].name,30);
}
textfile.close();

}
```

the record is only taking the first two lines and the rest is empty 
any ideas ??

Comment: Why use array instead of `string`? Also, you allow `getline` to read up to 30 characters, into a field that is 20 characters long.

Comment: Doesn't operator>> remove everything from the file not just a line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that:

```
textfile>>credentials[row].number;
```

while not consume the newline character. The subsequent call to `textfile.getline()` reads a blank line and the next:

```
textfile>>credentials[row].number;
```

attempts to read `"Goofy"` into an `int` which fails and set the failbit of the `textfile` stream meaning all further attempts to read fail. Check the return value to detect failure:

```
if (textfile >> credentials[row].number)
{
    // Success.
}
```

I am not entirely sure how the program ends as `"end"` will never be read but I suspect it ends abnormally as there is no mechanism to prevent overruning the end of the `credentials` array (i.e no `row < 30` as part of the loop terminating condition).

---

Other:

- Instead of using a fixed sized `char[]` to read the names into you can use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

  ```
  #include <string>

  struct record
  {
      std::string name;
      int number;
  };

  if (std::getline(textfile, credentials[row].name))
  {
  }
  ```
- Instead of using a fixed sized `record[]` you could use a [`std::vector<record>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which will grow as required.

Comment: i understand that the newline character is probably the problem here , however the number following mickey mouse is read into the record, it just fails to read Goofy and any others that follow. the 'end' is written in the text file at the end of all the entries . Im a little bit confused by the "check for return value to detect failure " . thanks for the quick response and help but could you explain a little more

Comment: Is it because the newline character isn't being recognised ? I ask because I based this on a previous program that worked the only difference is the use of getline on this one because of multiple words, ill try using strings and see if that works

Comment: @user1652319, the problem is that the read of the `int` using `operator>>` does **not** consume the new line character: it is recognised. You should always check return values to know if it succeeded and take appropriate action on failure.